# Android touchDown touchUp anywhere

Tags: java, android

I currently use this code to create taps on my rooted device

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
String cmd = "/system/bin/input tap 100 80\n";
os.writeBytes(cmd);
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
process.waitFor();
```

It works great and is able to tap anywhere I want, however I need to specify the tap duration (eg, touch down and wait 5 seconds before touch up) but this code uses the system's prefixed input tap which fixed the tap down and up time

Comment: You can record current time when user touch down, and record again when user touch up, then calculate time elapsed between these two times.

Comment: On user touch down create variable `long touchDown = System.currentTimeMillis();` then on touch up calculate the difference `long differnc = System.currentTimeMillis() - touchDown; differnc / 1000`' will give you the result you want.